# postscript merge two paths

Tags: compiler-construction, postscript

I am making a high-level language on top of postscript for my course on compilers, and I want to create two functions: concatenate and union, which should take two paths and joints them. Concatenate works by connecting the end point of the first path to the start point of the second. Union works does not connect the end points.

After playing for a while, I managed to perform those operations automatically. I got the intended result in some cases, but not in others. I will give concrete examples of my solution, and where they fail.

**WORKING:**
If I want to take two paths, one made by an arc, and other by connecting three dots, I can take the following basic paths:

```
 newpath 100 200 70 0 45 arc  %create an arc path
 newpath 100 100 moveto  200 200 lineto 200 300 lineto %create a polygon
```

and concatenate them (creating a line from the endpoint of the arc to the start point of the lines) by letting my compiler write the code:

```
newpath 100 100 moveto  200 200 lineto 200 300 lineto reversepath currentpoint newpath %stores the startpoint of the polygon to be used later

newpath 100 200 70 0 45 arc % creates the arc
lineto  %takes the saved information about start of the polygon and creates a line to it
100 100 moveto  200 200 lineto 200 300 lineto  %finishes by adding the polygon to the path
```

**STILL MISSING:**

I am operating on the raw strings that I used to create those paths, but how to proceed in the case the user had create bindings for paths, and now I want to join them. For example, supposed the user create the binds:

```
/p1 {  newpath 100 200 70 0 45 arc } bind def
/p2 {  newpath 100 100 moveto  200 200 lineto 200 300 lineto } bind def
```

How could I proceed to join these two paths as needed WITHOUT modifying the bindings?

I tried something like

```
p1 uappend p2
```

, but it didnt work. I can find no help even after looking for many days.

Thanks

Comment: So, your "compiler" takes postscript code (plus some higher level stuff) as input and also produces postscript code as output. But you haven't shown a definition of `uappend`.

Comment: uappend is a default postscript command, not from my compiler. My compiler is generating the strings shown by its own, so it's an output, not an input to the end-user. Inside the compiler itself, of course, it will be sometimes used as input.

Comment: Small suggestion: I would remove all the calls to `newpath`. Most of the time it will merely be useless, but occasionally it will be a positive hindrance to making more complex paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the definition of the functions and then look at the contents of the executable array.

```
/p1 load {==} forall
```

will show you what that looks like. Or you could define versions of each of the path operators which store their operands and just execute the procedures.

```
/moveto {....} def
/lineto {....} def
...
...
p1 p2
```

As usual with a programming problem there are multiple possible solutions.

Comment: I like the idea of redefining the path operators. For the working cases I have, I have to remove the /newpath operator of the second path so it wont restart, and it easy to do this from the compiler, but once its inside post/ghostscript, I dont see how to do it. I could use your trick to temporarily take the meaning out of /newpath, as if it was not there (Id achieve this bz doing /newpath {} def). But at some point later, I have to restore its original meaning. How can I restore the original meaning of this operator?

Comment: I tried to annulate the newpath temporarily by writing /newpath {} bind def, but this didnt take the meaning out of newpath. I'm confused

Comment: Well a PostScript program can always load the initial definition of newpath from systemict, which defeats the redefinition (systemdict is read-only so you can't normally replace those definitions). If you plan on using Ghostscript you can write your own operators in C (provided you are comfortable with compiling from source). You can also currently use -dWRITESYSTEMDICT to leave systemdict writeable, and -dDELAYBIND which defers binding until you run .bindnow. This is another way to allow you to redefine standard operators.

Comment: Ok, the redefinition of newpath was actually working, I just tested it wrong. Everything runs smooth now :). Now, I have a single approch to both pre-defined paths and to on the fly ones:

p1 reversepath currentpoint p2 lineto /newpath_backup {newpath} bind def /newpath { } bind def p1 /newpath {newpath_backup} bind def

--OR--

 newpath 100 200 70 0 45 arc reversepath currentpoint  newpath 100 100 moveto  200 200 lineto 200 300 lineto lineto /newpath_backup {newpath} bind def /newpath { } bind def  newpath 100 200 70 0 45 arc /newpath {newpath_backup} bind def 

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

You can join two procedures fairly easily since they're just arrays.

```
% [a] [b]  join  [ab]
/join { 2 array astore [ exch {{}forall}forall ] } def

/p1p2  //p1 //p2 join cvx  def
```

But, I repeat my comment: You should remove `newpath` because it's just getting in the way. It's almost never needed in PostScript programming. It does a hard reset side-effect which is generally not a good thing to do in all your functions. Somehow it got into the tutorials so everybody does it, but it doesn't do anything useful IME.

```
p1 uappend p2
```

This code suggests "infix thinking" so as a first pass we should correct this to

```
p1 p2 uappend
```

*But* `uappend` operates on *user-path objects* so you'll need to find an operator that takes the *current path* and returns a *user path object*.